# Can I force collection for objects of certain type only?

Tags: c#, .net, com, garbage-collection, rcw

I have [a problem with RCWs not being timely collected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29922000/57428). I think of periodically force-starting garbage collection from inside code. However I'm not sure if that will have some undesired slowdown.

I'm not actually interested in collecting all objects, I only need RCWs collected and they all have `System.__ComObject` type. I guess that collecting only them would be faster.

Is it possible to force garbage collection for objects of certain type only?

Comment: No, it isn't possible. Even when you force a GC, it's per generation.

Comment: Did you tried `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` or inspected the return value of `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, however I still have the problem. Maybe there's a bug and release isn't called everywhere.

Comment: @sharptooth Then I suggest you to fix that bug(or make sure there is none). You're trying to solve a different problem than what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It's not possible, you can only force a garbage collector to run but you can not force it to work according to your logic.

For more information on garbage collector please read this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx

Also GC is a static class, we can't override any of it's method :(